# How to use iptables to foward outbound web traffic to a proxy?

Tags: proxy, iptables

I've been hitting my head for a while as to how to do this. The scenario is as follows: I want to be able to forward all outbound web traffic from a browswer to Tor so that it is properly anonymized. Normally, one could just set the http proxy in the browser and be done with it but this is with a browser without the ability to do so specifically, a mobile browser.

So ideally, what could be done then is to intercept all web/dns traffic requests from the browser and send it to Tor. Assume for this, that Tor will be running on the device too.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't what you asked for but it might be of interest. Lets you proxify applications that don't have their own native proxy settings.
http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

As you're talking about iptables, i think your device is running Linux, what if you define your proxy in the HTTP_PROXY environment variable? I do this way with Chromium browser for example. Environment variables can be dynamicaly set using:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=proxy_ip:proxy_port
```

Comment: Browser does not understand HTTP_PROXY.